# Vue axios call is claiming argument is null when should be an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

In my vue component I have a data array

```
data: {
  categories: [{id:1, title: "category 1"},{id:2, title: "category 2"}]
}
```

and I'm trying to load this in as a data argument in an axios call

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: //testURL,
  data: {
    categoryCall: this.categories
  }
}).then(function (response){
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error){
  console.log(error.response);
});
```

but I'm getting a 400 bad request code where it tells me that argument 1 should be an array and null is given.

Am I not properly passing in the already established array in the axios call? Where am I going wrong?

```js
var vm = 
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    categories: [
    {id:1, title: "category 1"},
    {id:2, title: "category 2"}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    submit_axios(){
    
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: //test,
            data: {
              categories: this.categories
            }

        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
        });
    }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <button  @click="submit_axios()">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you're doing a get request but it doesn't support `data` because GET requests can't have request body. Docs: https://github.com/axios/axios/tree/v0.25.0#request-config "Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH'" is commented on `data`

Comment: Oh I see it now, I have to do this as a post and then return the data back as opposed to just using the GET method. Thank you, I think I've got it now

Comment: When a GET request returns HTTP status 400 the URL is either missing query-parameters or they contain invalid values like "argument 1 should be an array and null is given". Please post an [example].
What is the query-parameter expected? Can you post an example-URL (including a valid query) or the URL template as expected ?